# Switching between Classes with Buttons -- Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, class, button

I want to hit the pause button, then return to the previous class when buttons are clicked.  I am having no trouble going to the Pause class, but then I cannot get back.  Everything seems identical, so I think this may be a general hierarchy question or something like it, but I am not sure.

Pause class is called and runs correctly, but when I press the button, the program crashes.  I am trying to return to the same class which I just left.  I am using Eclipse.  Thanks for your help!  Here is my non-working code:

```
package com.evorlor.counter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Pause extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle instPause) {

        super.onCreate(instPause);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_counter);
        findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv.setTextSize(150);
        tv.setText("PAUSE");
    }

    public void resumeCounter(View view) {
        Intent resume = new Intent(Pause.this, Counter.class);
        startActivity(resume);
    }
}
```

---

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Pause" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPause"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnResume"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="resumeCounter" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

```
12-12 01:02:27.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1883): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 01:02:27.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1883): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method pauseCounter(View) in the activity class com.evorlor.counter.Pause for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button1'
12-12 01:02:27.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1883):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3584)
12-12 01:02:27.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1883):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
12-12 01:02:27.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1883):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
12-12 01:02:27.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1883):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-12 01:02:27.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1883):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-12 01:02:27.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1883):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-12 01:02:27.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1883):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
12-12 01:02:27.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1883):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 01:02:27.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1883):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-12 01:02:27.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1883):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
12-12 01:02:27.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1883):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
12-12 01:02:27.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1883):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-12 01:02:27.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1883): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: pauseCounter [class android.view.View]
12-12 01:02:27.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1883):     at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
12-12 01:02:27.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1883):     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
12-12 01:02:27.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1883):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3577)
12-12 01:02:27.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1883):     ... 11 more
```

---

Counter Class

```
package com.evorlor.counter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Counter extends Activity {

    private int count = 0;
    private int hiCount = 0;
    private boolean capCount = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle instCounter) {

        super.onCreate(instCounter);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_counter);
        findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        tv.setTextSize(250);
        if (count < 10000 && capCount == false) {

            tv.setText(Integer.toString(count));
        } else {
            capCount = true;
            if (count >= 10000) {
                hiCount += 10;
                count -= 10000;
            }
            if (hiCount < 100) {

                tv.setText(hiCount + "k+" + count);
            } else {
                tv.setText("Over\n100k");
            }
        }
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    }

    public void pauseCounter(View view) {
        Intent pause = new Intent(Counter.this, Pause.class);
        startActivity(pause);
    }

}
```

---

Counter layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Counter" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCounter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPause"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:onClick="pauseCounter" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same id for both buttons. Change one of the ids. Name it `button2` for example. Same with your TextViews, but they aren't referencing methods.

Comment: Thats because you used the **same** layout for both Activities. In Pause, change `setContentView(R.layout.activity_counter);` to *another* layout.

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: pauseCounter
```

Are you refering somewhere to a method called pauseCounter()? You problem lays there.

Furthermore,y ou need to set the layout first before reference(findViewById)

```
public class Pause extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle instPause) {

        super.onCreate(instPause);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_counter);
        findViewById(R.id.textView1); // move this here

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv.setTextSize(150);
        tv.setText("PAUSE");
        Button resume = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    resume.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();               
        }
    });
    }

  }
```

> Side note:

Try to name your button ids. Dont use default, it can cause problems very difficult to track.
try renaming them like this idBtnPause, idBtnResume and make sure you dont duplicate the names

Comment: @SamuelKnox See my edit. what is the method pauseCounter? we dont see it in your code. Exception occurs there

Comment: That is very strange, cuz when running the program, it changes to the pause class fine, but wont change back.

Comment: @SamuelKnox, see my edit . Another method to add a clicklistener.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried setting an onclick listener to tv

```
tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent resume = new Intent(Pause.this, Counter.class);
            startActivity(resume);


        }
    });
```

Comment: I have not.  That is not yet a part of my skill set.  Is that required?

Comment: if you are going to create a button or anything that need to be clicked to perform an action you need an onClick listener... read this [link]http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

Comment: He doesnt need to add a listener on the textview though. On the button yes, I agree with you.

Comment: @SamuelKnox it listens for actions such as clink action, long click, short click and when required gestures. and actions which should be performed in those instances